# How to fix add and delete in PHP/SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox, mysqli

I made a sort of rough of what more or less it would look like (minus the delete box and button, however I want it like the fav you see here).

[image]

I want to make a site that allows a user to add to a collection, then favorite with the click on a checkbox, and I want to add another checkbox to delete a gemstone if needed. I'm having problems with my checkbox that adds to the favorites table, how to delete, and adding to a collection. I'm looking for corrections, resources that could help me and psuedo code, but if I haven't given enough info let me know!

So this is my object-oriented favorites checkbox. Right now, the checkboxes are there but they're not functioning. There's some jQuery in there that is supposed to stop the user from faving more than 10. I look at this and it makes sense to me so kind of hard to see where I'm going wrong.

```
    $username = $_SESSION['USERNAME']; 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
        if(!empty($_POST['favorites'])){ 
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
            foreach($_POST['favorites'] as $selected){
                if($_POST['checkbox']==0)
                $_POST['checkbox'] = '';
                $query= "UPDATE u_collection SET fav = 0 WHERE username ='".$username."'"; 
                mysqli_query($db,$query);
                echo 'test';
            }
        } 
    } 
    if(isset($_POST['Collection'])){
    $query= "UPDATE u_collection SET gem = '".$i->name."' WHERE username ='".$username."'"; 
    mysqli_query($db,$query);
    }

foreach($gems as $i){
    echo '<tr> 
    <th>'.$i->name.'</th> 
    <th><form action="userhome.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox"'; 
    if(!empty($i->fav)){
        echo ' checked = "checked" ';         
    }
    echo 'name="favorites[]" value='.$i->name.'></th></tr></form>'; 
}

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('form input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
        if ($('form input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 10)
        {
           $(this).removeAttr('checked');
           alert('You are only allowed to select 10 checkboxes');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now the collection is really bothering me because I know it's simplifier than the previous problem, but my brain's drawing a blank. This is the code that is seen on the side, and there's a button that is to add to the user's collection. I'm trying to figure how I would do that with this object oriented variable, I'm assuming? I also need to add a delete button in the collection.

```
foreach($gemInfo as $i){
echo('
    <tr>  
        <th>
            <img src='.$i->image.'><br>
            <form action="userhome.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" value=".'$i->name'.">
                <input type="submit" name="Collection" value="+ Collection" />
            </form>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>'.$i->name.'</th>
    </tr>
    //rest of table'
    );
}
```

This is my first attempt at adding to the user's collection. It looks way wrong. I know I need to check the user's gems to see if it's already there, and it needs to be added to that user's part of the database, via session as used, but it doesn't make sense.

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $usql = "SELECT gem FROM gems WHERE gem = '".name."';";
    $ures =mysqli_query($db, $usql) or die(mysqli_error($db) ."<br>".$usql);
    $urow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ures);
    $d = $urow['gem'];
    if(isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] == 'add'){
        //check to see if already added
        $fchksql = "SELECT gem FROM u_collection WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['USERNAME']."'";
        $fchkres =mysqli_query($db, $fchksql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
        $fr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fchkres);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($fchkres);
        if($numrows < 1){
        $afsql = "INSERT INTO u_collection(gem) values('".$_SESSION['USERNAME']."','".$_GET['name']."',now());";
        mysqli_query($db, $afsql) or die(mysqli_error($db) ."<br>".$afsql);
        header("Location: ".$config_basedir."userprofile.php?u=".name);
        }//end if
```

Also, when adding, it becomes an array. How would you delete from an array or is that simpler than I thought?

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you the 55 check boxes  for the gems.  When submitted any unchecked will be removed and check are still checked.

Delete Button at added  top of page.

When you click the gem icon the check box will toggle.  the idea here is to put the check boxes in a div (within the form) with a style: `display:none;`.  This way the check boxes are still submitted but the user cannot see the actual check boxes.

Get the type of submission before anything is output to the Browser.

```
<?php 

$sub = intval($_POST['sub']);
if ($sub == 2){
  include('deleted.php');
  exit;
}


ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');
header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>Test Bed</title>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{width:2em;height:2em;border:2px solid #eee;outline:2px solid #eee;display: inline;margin:.3em;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;background:#144;color:#eee;   display: inline;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;}   
form{display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;}
.notselected,.selected {valign:top; border: 3px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:32px;height:32px;background-image: url('data:image/jpg;base64,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');}
.notselected{border: 3px solid #ff0;}
.selected{border: 3px solid #f00;}

.gemtext{font:700 1em Arial,sans-serif;}
```

**HTML**

```
</style></head><body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$userID" />

<input type="hidden" name="sub" value="2" />
<button type="submit"">Delete</button>
</form>
<form action="#" method="post">
<table>
EOT;
ob_flush();
$sub = intval($_POST['sub']);
for($i=0;$i<56;$i++){  // create temporary gems description
$gems[] = 'gem ' . $i;
}


$checks = array_fill(0,56,0);
$check = array('','checked="checked"');
$checked = array_fill(0,56,'');
$count = 0;
for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){$divs[] = $i;}  // Create 55 HTML check boxes
if($sub == 1){
  foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
    if(substr($k,0,3) == 'chk'){  // is it a check box?
      $checked[$v] = 'checked="checked"'; // embedded in HTML checkbox tag
      $checks[$v] = 1;            // If checked, change value to 1
      $count += 1;
    }
  }
}
$gclass = array('notselected','selected');
for($i=1;$i<56;$i++){
$gemclass = $gclass[$checks[$i]];
echo <<<EOT

<tr><td><input id="c$i" type="checkbox" name="chk$i" value="$i" $checked[$i]/></td><td><div id="g$i" class="$gemclass" onclick="ck($i)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >$gems[$i]</span> </td><tr></div>
EOT;
}  
echo <<<EOT
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1" />
<button type="submit"">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var c = new Array;
var d = new Array;
toggle = new Array;
toggle[true] = false;
toggle[false] = true;
bc = new Array;
bc[true] = '#f00';
bc[false] = '#ff0';
function ck(id){ 
  var div = document.getElementById('c' + id);
  div.checked = toggle[div.checked ];
  document.getElementById('g' + id).style.borderColor = bc[div.checked];
}

//]]>
</script>
</body></html>

EOT;
?>
```

### Snippet

```js
var c = new Array;
var d = new Array;
var count = 0;
var inc = new Array;
inc[true] = 1;
inc[false] = -1;
var warn = document.getElementById('warn');
toggle = new Array;
toggle[true] = false;
toggle[false] = true;
bc = new Array;
bc[true] = '#f00';
bc[false] = '#ff0';
function hide(){ 
  warn.style.display = 'none';
}
function ck(id){ 
  var div = document.getElementById('c' + id);
  div.checked = toggle[div.checked ];
  document.getElementById('g' + id).style.borderColor = bc[div.checked];
  count += inc[div.checked];
  if (count > 10){
    count = 10;
    document.getElementById('g' + id).style.borderColor = bc[false];
 div.checked = false;
    var posTop = div.offsetTop - 20; 
    warn.style.top = posTop + 'px'; 
    warn.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('cnt').innerHTML = count;
  }

  
}
```

```css
input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{width:2em;height:2em;border:2px solid #eee;outline:2px solid #eee;display: inline;margin:.3em;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;background:#144;color:#eee;   display: inline;vertical-align: middle;position: relative;}   
form{display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;}
.notselected,.selected {border: 3px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:32px;height:32px;background-image: url('data:image/jpg;base64,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');}
.notselected{border: 3px solid #ff0;}
.selected{border: 3px solid #f00;}
.gemtext{font:700 1em Arial,sans-serif;}
#warn{padding:1em;border:medium ridge #fff;display:none;z-index:11;position:absolute;top:0px;left:20px;width:14em;font:700 2em Arial,sans-serif;background:#f00;color:#fff;}
#page{position:relative;font:700 1em serif;}
p,h2{margin:0;}
h2{padding-top:.2em;}
```

```html
<div id="page">
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="sub" value="2" />
<button type="submit"">Delete</button>
</form>
<p>The check boxes are disabled.  This is to show how when clicking on the gem icon the check box gets checked.<br/>
<p>Normally the check boxes would be in a div with a style display:none<br/>
<p>If you try to select more than 10 check boxes, a warning will pop up, and the check box is not checked.<br/>
<form action="#" method="post">
<div id="warn" onclick="hide()">You are only allowed to select 10 checkboxes</div>
<table><div><h2>Number Selected: <span id="cnt">0</span></h2><div>
<tr><td><input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="1" disabled /></td><td><div id="g1" class="notselected" onclick="ck(1)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 1</span> </td>
<td><input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="chk2" value="2" disabled /></td><td><div id="g2" class="notselected" onclick="ck(2)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 2</span> </td>
<td><input id="c3" type="checkbox" name="chk3" value="3" disabled /></td><td><div id="g3" class="notselected" onclick="ck(3)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 3</span> </td>
<td><input id="c4" type="checkbox" name="chk4" value="4" disabled /></td><td><div id="g4" class="notselected" onclick="ck(4)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 4</span> </td>
<td><input id="c5" type="checkbox" name="chk5" value="5" disabled /></td><td><div id="g5" class="notselected" onclick="ck(5)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 5</span> </td><tr>

<tr><td><input id="c6" type="checkbox" name="chk6" value="6" disabled /></td><td><div id="g6" class="notselected" onclick="ck(6)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 6</span> </td>
<td><input id="c7" type="checkbox" name="chk7" value="7" disabled /></td><td><div id="g7" class="notselected" onclick="ck(7)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 7</span> </td>
<td><input id="c8" type="checkbox" name="chk8" value="8" disabled /></td><td><div id="g8" class="notselected" onclick="ck(8)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 8</span> </td>
<td><input id="c9" type="checkbox" name="chk9" value="9" disabled /></td><td><div id="g9" class="notselected" onclick="ck(9)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 9</span> </td>
<td><input id="c10" type="checkbox" name="chk10" value="10" disabled /></td><td><div id="g10" class="notselected" onclick="ck(10)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 10</span> </td><tr>

<tr><td><input id="c11" type="checkbox" name="chk11" value="11" disabled /></td><td><div id="g11" class="notselected" onclick="ck(11)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 11</span> </td>
<td><input id="c12" type="checkbox" name="chk12" value="12" disabled /></td><td><div id="g12" class="notselected" onclick="ck(12)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 12</span> </td>
<td><input id="c13" type="checkbox" name="chk13" value="13" disabled /></td><td><div id="g13" class="notselected" onclick="ck(13)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 13</span> </td>
<td><input id="c14" type="checkbox" name="chk14" value="14" disabled /></td><td><div id="g14" class="notselected" onclick="ck(14)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 14</span> </td>
<td><input id="c15" type="checkbox" name="chk15" value="15" disabled /></td><td><div id="g15" class="notselected" onclick="ck(15)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 15</span> </td><tr>

<tr><td><input id="c16" type="checkbox" name="chk16" value="16" disabled /></td><td><div id="g16" class="notselected" onclick="ck(16)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 16</span> </td>
<td><input id="c17" type="checkbox" name="chk17" value="17" disabled /></td><td><div id="g17" class="notselected" onclick="ck(17)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 17</span> </td>
<td><input id="c18" type="checkbox" name="chk18" value="18" disabled /></td><td><div id="g18" class="notselected" onclick="ck(18)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 18</span> </td>
<td><input id="c19" type="checkbox" name="chk19" value="19" disabled /></td><td><div id="g19" class="notselected" onclick="ck(19)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 19</span> </td>
<td><input id="c20" type="checkbox" name="chk20" value="20" disabled /></td><td><div id="g20" class="notselected" onclick="ck(20)"></div></td><td><span class="gemtext" >gem 20</span> </td><tr></table></div>
<input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1" />
<button type="submit"">Submit</button>
</form></div>
```

Comment: OK, sorry about that. I took out HTML to shorten the post and didn't clean up well. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: ok, I'm working on it still.  I should have something very soon.  see update

Comment: do you have a link to a publicly available page? If they can check only 10 how many gems are there total.

Comment: There are a total of 55 gems that can be added to their collection and once their collection has that gem, then they can check the box to and click a submit button to save their progress. Thanks again.

Comment: As for the link, no I don't have one because I'm still working out the bugs... Quite the project this has been!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77223/discussion-between-icoder-and-misunderstood).